# When testing a Backbone+RequireJS app is it better to load the whole app upfront?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, requirejs, mocha.js

I am trying to choose a setup for testing a webapp that uses Backbone and RequireJS.

I will try to do most of my unit testing from javascript and I am in doubt whether it is better to load my whole app before calling the testing framework or to use RequireJS to dinamycally load just the modules that are being tested by each test.

As this site is just for Q&A and not open to discussion, I will reformulate: Do you have any strong argument against not loading the whole app upfront when unit testing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to test each of your Models/Collections/Views separately in unit test. Starting the whole app in a unit test would it made really hard to test all cases for a module. As you mention requireJS you should also mock most of the dependencies of a module using [squireJS](https://github.com/iammerrick/Squire.js/).

But you should additionally have some integration tests where you test the behavior of the whole app in a headless browser using a tool like selenium, casperJS or capybara.

Comment: In fact, I meant loading the whole app before starting the test suite. However, I guess that would avoid the tests from being executed independently.

Answer (score 0):

With requirejs, there are two ways for you to interpret loading upfront:

- During development, where r.js is not be used, and just depend on configuration on requirejs.config
- After r.js optimization, where the modules can be restructure by r.js configuration

Comment: In my test environment I don't use r.js, therefore by "loading upfront" I mean loading my application's `main.js`.

Comment: Then you can assess the situation and see if loading every upfront will slow down the initial page loading. If it is, it will be better to break it up to lazy loading by modules.